# Android : Espresso test FW throwing "No tests found.." exception

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I'm trying to start with Espresso FW for automatized UI testing by this article:

http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html

So i installed all dependencies and i created following testing class for the MainActivity.

```
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import activities.MainActivity;
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;


/**
 * Created by xxx on 19.8.2015.
 */
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public MainActivityTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        mActivity = getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void buttonShouldUpdateText(){
        onView(withId(R.id.goToSecondActivityBtn)).perform(click());
        //onView(withId(getResourceId("Click"))).check(matches(withText("Hello world!")));
    }
}
```

But if i clicked on the "Run activity test" button i always get following error message:

```
Running tests
Test running started
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.example.mypackage.test.MainActivityTest
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at junit.framework.TestSuite$1.runTest(TestSuite.java:97)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestResult.runProtected(DelegatingTestResult.java:90)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.run(AndroidTestResult.java:49)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.NonLeakyTestSuite$NonLeakyTest.run(NonLeakyTestSuite.java:63)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestSuite.run(DelegatingTestSuite.java:103)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestSuite.run(AndroidTestSuite.java:63)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:228)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
```

I tried to use different annotations by this article:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTestingEspresso/article.html

But without the luck.

How can i solve it to run a simple test on Main Activity please ?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run JUnit 4 style tests, you need to annotate the test class with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)`

i.e.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working. But why annotattion @RunWith is not mentioned in the examples links and their tests are working too?

Comment: Which examples are you talking about? The official ones are just code snippets and most of them wouldn't even compile. The Vogella ones all have the annotation as far as I can see...

Comment: You can refer these examples. They run well! https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `test` before your function:

```
@Test
public void testbuttonShouldUpdateText(){
    onView(withId(R.id.goToSecondActivityBtn)).perform(click());
    //onView(withId(getResourceId("Click"))).check(matches(withText("Hello world!")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should rename your `buttonShouldUpdateText()` to `testButtonShouldUpdateText()`.
all the method should start with `test`.

also, you should use JUnit 4 style,it only add a annotation to the method to be tested.